# How to retain a selection/get new indexes after sorting a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

This might be simple, but I'm unable to wrap my head around it.

I have a list such as:

```
list_a = [['Peter', '2016'],['David', '2020'],['Ulrik', '2018'],['Lars', '2017'],['Dave', '2019'],['Ann', '2015']]
```

A user is then able to select some items, lets say `['Peter', '2016']` and `['Lars', '2017']`. The selection is then stored as indexes like:

```
user_selection = [0,3]
```

Now, i wish to sort `list_a` like:

```
list_a.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=False)
```

The list is now ordered by date and looks like:

```
list_a = [['Ann', '2015'], ['Peter', '2016'], ['Lars', '2017'], ['Ulrik', '2018'], ['Dave', '2019'],['David', '2020']]
```

However, as you've guessed from my title, `user_selection` is now "wrong" and refers to items the user did not select. How do i "update" the selection (or sort it along with the list) so it becomes:
`user_selection = [1,2]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rework of my answer:

Here a full example:

```
list_a = [['Peter', '2016'],['David', '2020'],['Ulrik', '2018'],['Lars', '2017'],['Dave', '2019'],['Ann', '2015']]
```

this is your list.

If `user_selection` is now following:

```
user_selection = [0,3]
```

You could do following:

```
user_selected_lists = [] # a list where we safe the inputs from list_a which the user selected

for selected in user_selection:
   user_selected_lists.append(list_a[selected]) # this takes the item at the index the user selected and safes it into the `user_selected_lists`

# Now you have the both lists the user selected in the `user_selected_lists`

new_indexes = [] # the new indexes of the selected lists
for selected_list in user_selected_lists:
    new_indexes.append(list_a.index(selected))  # this gets the new index from the new list of each list we safed from the first list.
```

And there you go it should work. Haven't tried it but the logic should work.

Or the simple way.

```
list_a_duplicate = list_a    # make a duplicate from list_a

list_a.sort()   # sort the list as you wish

# If you want now to know what index 0 and 3 are NOW after sorting you can just do following.

old_indexes_now = []   # the new indexes
for index in user_selection:
   list_item = list_a_duplicate[index] # get each item of the old list
   new_index = list_a.index(list_item) # get the index of the item from the new list
   old_indexes_now.append(new_index)
```

I hope its understandable for you now.

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution, I will be testing this out within the hour and get back to you

Comment: No problem have a look at it again because I updated my answer. (Forgot a few things)

Comment: I can't quite get it to work, still trying to get it implemented, perhaps if you have the time you could make me a full example? It's ok if you don't.

I will try more and get back

Comment: Hi I updated it again with a full example and descripted it a bit better i hope. Tell me if its understandable now

Comment: Little hint. You cant use this if your list has duplicates like ['Peter', '2016'],['Peter, '2016']

Comment: Because then the function --> .index() will search for ['Peter', '2016'] and will find 2 ... i think it then will take the first but im not sure

Comment: Btw you missed the actual sorting in the first example, but I figured out where to put it thanks to your help, thank you again!